# Android Studio: How to create build.gradle file for use on Jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle and trying to figure out how to set it up on our Jenkins build machine. Our app builds perfectly from within Android Studio, but it doesn't ever generate a build.gradle file, which I believe I need in order to run the gradle build on Jenkins.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up creating these build files from scratch.

Here's some guidelines:

1. If you have a project with multiple modules, create a settings.gradle file at the root of your project (at the same level as all the modules). Your settings.gradle file should look something like this:

   ```
   include 'ActionBarSherlock'
   include ':facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1:facebook'
   include 'google-play-services_lib'
   include ':SlidingMenu-master:library'
   include 'Tinder'
   include 'ViewPagerIndicator'
   include 'volley'
   include 'windowed-seek-bar'
   ```
2. Within each module, create a build.gradle file. For library projects, your build.gradle file should look something like this:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }

       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
       }
   }

   apply plugin: 'android-library'

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
   }

   android {
       buildToolsVersion "17.0"
       compileSdkVersion 17

       sourceSets {
           main {
               manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
               java.srcDirs = ['src']
               resources.srcDirs = ['src']
               aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
               renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
               res.srcDirs = ['res']
               assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
           }

           instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
       }
   }
   ```
3. For your main project, your build.gradle file should look like this:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }

       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
       }
   }

   apply plugin: 'android'

   dependencies {
       compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1:facebook')
       compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
       compile project(':SlidingMenu-master:library')
       compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
       compile project(':volley')
       compile project(':windowed-seek-bar')
       compile files('compile-libs/androidannotations-2.7.1.jar', 'libs/Flurry_3.2.1.jar', 'libs/google-play-services.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar', 'libs/picasso-1.1.1.jar')
   }

   android {
       buildToolsVersion "17.0"
       compileSdkVersion 17

       sourceSets {
           main {
               manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
               java.srcDirs = ['src']
               resources.srcDirs = ['src']
               aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
               renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
               res.srcDirs = ['res']
               assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have been searching for info on this and this short answer is more useful than many 'tutorials'... I have one question thou, how do you run the build this way, which build.gradle file gets 'executed'?

Comment: The build.gradle file in your main module should be executed. In my case, "Tinder".