# How to create a basic "build.gradle" file?

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio

i download OpenCV library then unzip it and serf the library and saw that include a samples

[image]

They was show at screenshot.

When i try to open it with AndroidStudio, it dont understand that it's app. And the first a got massege

[image]

i skip it and open the tree of the project

and that's how it looks

[image]

As far as i understand the fact is that sample is IntelliJ "classic" projects. And if i want migrate it in Gradle-based projects i should make some step according this [tutorial](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects) .

And the first stap say us -Create a basic "build.gradle" file

How i can create it?

Comment: Probably this samples are for Eclipse IDE. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

Comment: i think i have problem because of this http://goo.gl/0uRekl

Comment: This will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432325/android-studio-how-to-create-build-gradle-file-for-use-on-jenkins

Comment: i have already found that post but he said in the first step "create a settings.gradle file" but how create this file? Studio provide us create XML or java file there are not .gradle file? this is excatly my quetion